# How to find $x_1$?

Tags: newton-raphson, numerical-calculus

> let $f(x) =x^2-5$ for  $x \in \mathbb{R}$ . Let $x_0 =1$ . If $\{x_n\}$  denotes the  sequence  of iterates   defined by  the newton -raphson method to approximate  a   solution  of $f(x)=0$ . Find $x_1$

My attempt : i know the The Newton-Raphson Method is:

$$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$$

Now  by applying this  formula  on the  given question

$$x_{n+1}  =  x_n - \frac{x_n^2-5}{2x}$$

After that im not able to proceed  further

Comment: The denominator of your last equation should have $x_n$, not simply $x$.

Comment: Let $n$ be $0$, and that equation becomes $x_1=\cdots$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your iteration should be
$$
x_{n+1}
 = x_n - \frac{x_n^2-5}{2x_n}
 = \frac{x_n^2+5}{2x_n}
 = \frac{x_n}{2} + \frac{5}{2x_n}
$$
So for $n=0$ can you finish the problem?

Comment: thanks  u @gt6988  i think it should be   $x_n/2  +  5/2x_n=  1/2 + 5/2 =3$

Comment: @jasmine correct

Answer (score 2):

$$x_1 = x_0 - \frac{f(x_0)}{f'(x_0)} = 1-\frac{f(1)}{f'(1)} = 1-\frac{-4}{2} = 3.$$

Comment: Fixed! Thank you.